# Amazon Aws is charging for free tier

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I have got 75 dollars and 1 years of free tier uses in amazon awseducate. it is called amazon aws student starter pack. I created only one ec2 instance and one rds in free tier. But Amazon is charging from the 75 dollars every day. Even I cannot issue a support ticket. Because student account can't create a support ticket.
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/educate-starter-account/

Comment: Not really a question here but you should check to see if you aren’t getting charged for additional tack ons, like load balancing etc

Comment: If you're being charged, then it isn't really a free tier, right?

Comment: Not the right place to ask the question.. You would probably try to call them

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this a aws support question

Comment: I have already mentioned that I couldn't create support ticket because my iam role doesn't support that.

Comment: How are you the person being billed, but you aren't the root account owner?

Comment: It sounds like you are using [AWS Educate](https://aws.amazon.com/education/awseducate/). I thought they automatically get turned off after using $75? Anyway, you can [contact AWS Educate customer service](https://aws.amazon.com/education/awseducate/contact-us/) (which is different to Customer Support). Select **Account and Billing Support**.

Comment: John Rotenstein, thank you for link.they mailed me that awseducate doesnt support free tiers. But i was confused about making support ticket. Because from aws console support ticket creating was blocked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Having the free tier doesn't mean everything is free - there are certain products, and certain levels of products that are free - if you use products or services outside the designated free options, you will need to pay - sometimes a lot.

For example, you can use 1 free ec2 instance of the t2 type free for a year (I believe its only the t2-small).

If you spin up a d2.8xlarge instead, and leave it running all year you will have a bill of almost $50K - so pay attention to what is free and what you are using; check your bill often,  and contact aws support on their support forums or at the /r/aws forum on reddit.

Comment: Also check for space being used, there is a limit to that in free tier. Usage above limitation adds on to bill.

Comment: when I was creating an instance it was telling 30 gb disk space is free with those instances. but I cant know which purpose I was billed for because my iam role didn't give the permission.

Comment: @FahimAbrar Then you need to login with the root account to check your bill. The root user can also grant billing access to IAM users.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is the aws educate doesnt support free tier.Most student get confused about support ticket because aws support ticket is blocked from account console. But there is another ink for awseducate support. I dont know why they make two support service different here is the link https://aws.amazon.com/education/awseducate/contact-us/